# Optional Character in PHP Regular Expression Replace

Tags: php, regex

I have data in this format coming from a database...

```
BUS 101S Business and Society
```

or

```
BUS 101 Business and Society
```

Notice the optional "S" character (which can be any uppercase character)

I need to replace the "BUS 101S" part with null and here is what I have come up with...

```
$value = "BUS 101S Business and Society";
$sub = substr($value, 0, 3); // Gives me "BUS"
$num = substr($value, 4, 3); // Gives me "101"
$new_value = preg_replace("/$sub $num"."[A-Z]?/", null, $value);
```

The value of `$new_value` now contains `S Business and Society`. So I'm close, Just need it to replace the optional single uppercase character as well. Any ideas?

Comment: your code already works as-is for me, but there are simpler ways to do it!

Comment: Hmmm... that's strange. I agree there are simpler ways haha glad I am seeing that now from the answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the pattern is 3 uppercase letters, 3 numbers and then an optional uppercase letter, just use a single `preg_match`:

```
$new = preg_replace('/^[A-Z]{3} \d{3}[A-Z]?/', '', $old);
```

The `^` will only match at the beginning of a line/string. The `{3}` means "match the preceding token 3 times exactly". The `?` means "match the preceding token zero or one times"

Comment: Well I've tried your code in a new PHP file with what I posted in my question and it works great so this is the answer to my question, why it doesn't work in my other code is making me pull my hair out but there must be another problem other than what I posted in my question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this, so you don't bother with substr:

```
preg_replace('#^[A-Z]{3} [0-9]{3}[A-Z]? (.*)$#', '$1', $value);
```

Or using preg_match, to get all the components of the string

```
if (preg_match('#^([A-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{3})([A-Z]?) (.*)$#', $value, $matches)) {
    $firstMatch=$matches[1];//BUS ($matches[0] is the whole string)
    $secondMatch=$matches[2];//101
    $secondMatch=$matches[3];//S or ''
    $secondMatch=$matches[4];//the rest of the text
}
```

Comment: I agree, though I do need `substr()` because I use those variables later on, but thanks for pointing that out to simplify the reading of the regex.

Comment: Then you can use preg_match, see my updated answer (in a few minutes)

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing that out! Wish I could accept two answers...

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it just be easier to do something like:

```
$str = 'BUS 101S Business and Society';
$words = explode(' ', $str);
array_unshift($words); // bus
array_unshift($words); // 101s
$str = implode(' ', $words);
```